# how to fetch the objects in dm_acl who grants the same sets of permission at the same time

Tags: dql, documentum

I am doing a `JavaFx` project connected to `Documentum` data source . lets say I have a set of groups : group1 , group2 , group3 
How can I query all the `acl_names` from `dm_acl` who has `only and exactly` these groups as their `r_acceesor_name` . For example using the following query I can get the r_accessor_name of a specific acl:

```
select r_acceessor_name from dm_acl where object_name = 'My_acl_name' enable (row_based)
```

and the output is :

```
group1
group2
group3
```

But what I want to do is the reverse of this .I've tried the following query :

```
select object_name from dm_acl where r_accessor_name = 'group1' or r_accessor_name = 'group2' or r_accessor_name = 'group3' enable (row_based)
```

But the problem with the output is that it's too general which makes sense because  of keyword `OR`
then I tried this :

```
select object_name from dm_acl where r_accessor_name = 'group1' and r_accessor_name = 'group2' and r_accessor_name = 'group3' enable (row_based)
```

which is too specific ==> zero output

Comment: you made very confusing question. Try presenting your question to your grandma and then write it here. First your need or problem you need to solve and then what you've done.

Comment: @Miki question is updated

Comment: btw, on every question you make regarding Documetnum you start with your project. It is irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused yourself more than you can think of. 
Every ACL object has at least two entries: `dm_owner` and `dm_world` where first represents repository owner and the last represents every user in repository.

Because of it your objective

... all the `acl_names` from `dm_acl` who has **only and exactly** these groups ...

cannot be achieved. 
However, beside this, your query

```
SELECT object_name FROM dm_acl 
WHERE r_accessor_name = 'group1' 
AND r_accessor_name = 'group2' 
AND r_accessor_name = 'group3' 
ENABLE (ROW_BASED)
```

is the best you can get. Your problem is that you really don't have ACL in your repository that contains at least these 3 groups. This leads you to the your initial question: either you made wrong presumption either you tried to too much to generalize your question that you've omitted the important part of it. ;)

Comment: I think your query always returns 0 rows, as the conditions in WHERE clause can not ever match. When you use ROW_BASED hint, each row in a result set has exactly one value for repeating attribute, so when you are trying to say give me object with the name 'a' AND name 'b' it will never return you anything

Answer (score 1):

I think I read your mind and came to what you really need:

```
SELECT object_name FROM dm_acl 
WHERE r_accessor_name IN ('group_A', 'group_B', 'group_C')  
GROUP BY object_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r_accessor_name) = 2 
ENABLE (row_based)
```

Try it and see if it'll work.